# Compare dates on static block widget in Magento 2

Tags: magento, magento2

I have two dates fields in my CMS block in Magento 2. I want the CMS block to only show when we are in range of dates.

For this I override a block function `_beforeToHtml`.

Now I am using a function which looks like this:

```
if($inRange) {
    $this->setText($this->_filterProvider->getBlockFilter()->setStoreId($storeId)->filter($block->getContent())
                );
}
```

But the problem is due to cache problem it will work after only flushing a cache in Magento 2.

Answer (score 0):

Try to write code in phtml file and call that phtml file in block by using following code. this may avoid cache issue.

Block call example:

```
{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Webkul_Test::test.phtml"}}
```

[Reference link](https://webkul.com/blog/call-phtml-file-cms-page-magento2/)

Comment: Thanks  for your reply,
I want to insert a block via admin panel so how to done via this way

Comment: Admin static block i am showing to frontend, that is not displaying, so how to show cms_block to to page in magento that cache issues is resolved.

Comment: Provided reference link in my answer, please follow the steps.